# Neutral element of singular matrix

Tags: matrices

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        a & 0 & a \\
        0 & 0 & 0 \\
        a & 0 & a \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$  I need to find the neutral element of this matrix in a multiplicative group. I'm thinking that a singular matrix can't have the neutral element be the unit matrix but how can I find it's neutral element then?

Comment: Right, in a multiplicative group of matrices, this matrix does not belong to it, since it has no inverse.

Comment: I'd post a photo but someone told me it's not okay to put pictures so I'm gonna try to explain the problem and sorry if my english is bad.So I have $$M={A_a|a is a real number}$$ and M with multiplication is a monoid where $A_a$ has the form given above.In the book it asks for the neutral element(unity element) and the inverse of A(1) for the first one the answers is $A_1/2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dietrich Burde , you are wrong (it's the first time :)  )

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&1\\0&0&0\\1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$; since $A^2=2A$, the set $G=\{aA;a\in K\}$ is a semi group for multiplication of matrices ($K$ is a field with characteristic $\geq 5$).

In fact $G$ is a group; to prove that, it suffices to find a matrix $N\in G$ s.t. $NA=AN=A$ and a matrix $A'\in G$ s.t. $AA'=A'A=N$.

Of course, the solution is unique and is $N=(1/2)A,A'=(1/4)A$.

Comment: could you tell me where I can find more info about semigroups please? especially this type